# Very poor MySQL query performance after upgrading from server-5.5 to server-5.6

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm in the process of trying to migrate a database from an old server to a new one. The old server is running an Xampp installation which has been more than adequate for the use case. For the new server I installed a newer version of Xampp and copied the database over. All good so far...

There is also a batch script that runs which pulls info from a number of text files into the DB which runs in an infinite loop. Every 5 loops, the script calls an data history update query which basically adds 72 records to a large history table. This is done with 72 calls to a stored procedure.

The problem is, the history update takes approx 40secs to complete on the old server but 40mins on the new one. I've spent 4 days trying every possible setting I could think of to improve the performance and even tried to replicate the my.ini on the old server to see what happened but the same values are not improving the performance.

It's not a hardware issue because the new server is better than the old one so I'm stumped at this stage...

Anyone know what I can do to try and trace the issue or what I can do to improve the scenario?

All tables are MyISAM on the old server and I tried converting to InnoDB but the performance was even worse that way...

**Old Server:**

MySQL version: 5.5.8-log

**New server:**

MySQL version: 5.6.20

`SHOW VARIABLES` http://pastebin.com/AZFvTkQ5

`SHOW STATUS` http://pastebin.com/Ms9NxrrB

Comment: It sounds like you're missing indexes.

Comment: @BenOastler Hi Ben, the indexes are all identical...

Comment: Are you able to identify which part of the history update script is blowing out? Or is it a single update query?

Comment: Could you paste a 'show variables' and 'show status' to pastebin? I would also recommend monyog - it helped me a ton for troubleshooting a new env/server migration.

Comment: And what are mysql versions?

Comment: @BenOastler It seems that every query in the routine is taking longer for some reason

Comment: @cerd I edited the question with the info you requested

Comment: @doovers - I experienced some performance issues relating to indexes when I moved from 5.5 to 5.6 - can you run and post output for 'SHOW CREATE TABLE <name_of_history_table>;' on ea. server and post?

Comment: @cerd Good idea and the result solved the issue! It turned out that the primary key had a different charset and collation to the table. I matched these and it fixed the problem! If you want to post an answer I'll give you the credit because it would have taken me ages to figure that out! On another note, I didn't think a mismatch like that would have such a major performance impact!

Comment: @doovers - will do. I suggest editing Title to be along the lines of: "Very poor mysql query performance after upgrading from server-5.5 to server-5.6"